# AutoCompletetextview custom adapter issue

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have one autocomplete text view that display firm name from sq-lite database. from the database records are came properly there is no issue.but issue is adapter .adapter is not clear like first i search something and suggestion display than remove it and again type and there is no suggestion in database but adapter is display old suggestion that is search in last.
Below i put images so clearly identify whats the problem

[This image for write output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMF3T.png)

[this is wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMF3T.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMF3T.png):[image]

[image]
Here is my code for topuptransfer.java

```
public class TopupTransfer extends BaseActivity{

    AutoCompleteTextView memberView;
    ArrayList <String> name = null,name1= null;
    Button btnSubmit;
    String membercode2,amount;
    EditText amnt,smspin;;
    HashMap<String,String> memberDetail;
    AutoCompleteAdapter2 adapter;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.topuptransfer);
        if(!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof ExceptionHandler))
        {
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        }
        /*ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);*/

        db = new DatabaseHelper(TopupTransfer.this);

        memberView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        name = new ArrayList<String>();
        name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        memberDetail = new HashMap<String,String>();
        amnt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.topup_amnt);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        smspin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smspin);

        EditText mobileno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileno);
        mobileno.setText(ResponseString.getMobno());

        if(ResponseString.getRequiredSmsPin().equals("TRUE"))
        {
            smspin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            smspin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        memberView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String text = s.toString();
                Log.d("text", "" + text);
                //adapter.clear();
                int len = text.length();
                if (memberView != null)
                {
                if( len >= 3) {
                    Log.d("text", "" + text);
                    try {
                           if(name1 != null){name1.clear();}
                           name1 = GetList(text);
                           Log.d("name1", "" + name1.size());
                           if(ResponseString.getStcode().equals("0")) {
                               if (name1.size() != 0) {
                                    Log.d("ADPTER LIST", name1.toString());
                                    //adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(TopupTransfer.this, R.layout.listview_raw,R.id.desc, name1);
                                   adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter2(TopupTransfer.this,R.id.desc, name1);
                                   memberView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                           }
                           else {
                                Toast.makeText(TopupTransfer.this, "" + BaseActivity.sMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                        }catch(Exception e){

                            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(TopupTransfer.this));
                            //throw new RuntimeException("Check in Topup transfer");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(ResponseString.getRequiredSmsPin().equals("TRUE"))
                {
                    String sms = smspin.getText().toString();
                    String rs = ResponseString.getSmspwd();

                    if (sms.length() == 0) {
                        toastValidationMessage(TopupTransfer.this, getResources().getString(R.string.plsentersmspin));
                        smspin.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if (!sms.equals(rs)) {
                        toastValidationMessage(TopupTransfer.this, getResources().getString(R.string.pinentercorrect));
                    }
                }

                if (memberView.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    toastValidationMessage(TopupTransfer.this, getResources().getString(R.string.plsenterfirm));
                    memberView.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }else if (amnt.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    toastValidationMessage(TopupTransfer.this, getResources().getString(R.string.plsenteramnt));
                    amnt.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                String Dpattern = memberView.getText().toString();
                membercode2 = BaseActivity.detailMember.get(Dpattern);
                amount = amnt.getText().toString();

                Log.d("membercode",""+ membercode2);
                Log.d("amount", "" + amount);
                try {

                    if (membercode2.equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(TopupTransfer.this, "Firm name is not Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        boolean con = isInternetConnected();
                        if (con) {
                            AsyncTaskCommon asy = new AsyncTaskCommon(TopupTransfer.this, membercode2, amount);
                            stcode = asy.execute("TopupTransfer").get();
                            /*int i = 0;
                            //BaseActivity.showProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                            while (!BaseActivity.baseResponse) {
                                i++;
                            }*/
                            if(stcode.equals("0"))
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TopupTransfer.this);
                                builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                                builder.setMessage(BaseActivity.sMsg);
                                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        BaseActivity.sMsg = "";
                                        finish();
                                        Intent m = new Intent(TopupTransfer.this,TopupTransfer.class);
                                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                                        startActivity(m);
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                toastValidationMessage(TopupTransfer.this, sMsg);
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(TopupTransfer.this, "Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(TopupTransfer.this));
                }
            }
        });

    }
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                            return true;
                        }
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_signout:
            logout(TopupTransfer.this);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}

ArrayList<String> GetList(String text) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayListtemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.getTimeRecordList(text, "ChildUserInfo");
    if (cursor != null){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                arrayListtemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FirmName")));// added your table value from database
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
        return arrayListtemp;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          doExit();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
private void doExit() {
       finish();
       Intent intent = new Intent(TopupTransfer.this,HomePage.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

For adapter class
AutoCompleteAdapter.java

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements  Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> fullList = null;
    private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues= null;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter = null;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> fullList) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, fullList);
        this.fullList = fullList;
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fullList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return fullList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        private Object lock;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);
                }
            }

            ArrayList<String> queryResults;
            if (prefix != null && prefix.length() >= 3 && mOriginalValues != null) {
                queryResults = autocomplete(prefix.toString());
            } else {
                queryResults = new ArrayList<String>(); // empty list/no suggestions showing if there's no valid constraint
            }
            results.values = queryResults;
            Log.d("results2",""+results.values);
            results.count = queryResults.size();
            Log.d("results count2 ",""+results.count);
            return results;

        }

        private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
            ArrayList<String> queryResults = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(mOriginalValues != null) {
                ArrayList<String> values = mOriginalValues;
                int count = values.size();
                if (count >= 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        String item = values.get(i);
                        queryResults.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return queryResults;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            if (results.values != null) {
                Log.d("results",""+results.values);
                fullList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                Log.d("fullist",""+fullList.toString());
            } else {
                fullList = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                Log.d("result count", "" + results.count);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: variable of top-up transfer class file --name1 variable size  is 0 when i will try wrong input in autocomplete text view.

Comment: From your code i can see you are performing filter on FullList, and you have originallist as well, but you never reinitialize fulllist with original list if you clear your auto complete text.

Comment: sorry i can't understand what u say. if u have no problem , edit my code and posted it. thanks in advanced. - Silvans Solanki

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NotifyDataSetChanged after updating your adapter to populate new data

```
 if(ResponseString.getStcode().equals("0")) {
                                   if (name1.size() != 0) {
                                        Log.d("ADPTER LIST", name1.toString());
                                        //adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(TopupTransfer.this, R.layout.listview_raw,R.id.desc, name1);
                                       adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter2(TopupTransfer.this,R.id.desc, name1);
                                       memberView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                       adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged():
                                    }
                               }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved in my case please check it out :

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter

{

    Context               context;
    private ArrayList< Employee > employeelist ;
    private ArrayList< Employee > arraylist;



    public EmployeeAdapter( Context context2, ArrayList< Employee > employeeList2)
    {
        this.context = context2;
        this.employeelist = employeeList2;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(employeelist);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return  employeelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

         return employeelist.get(position).getEMPLOYEEID();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = ( ( Activity ) context ).getLayoutInflater();
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if ( convertView == null )
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.cursor_row, null );
            holder = new ViewHolder();

           holder.employeename = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.textcursor );


            convertView.setTag( holder );

        }
        else
        {

            holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag();
        }




        holder.empname=employeelist.get( position ).getNAME();
        holder.empid=employeelist.get( position ).getEMPLOYEEID();


        holder.employeename.setText(holder.empname );




        convertView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {


                //context.startActivity(new Intent(context, EmployeeActivity.class));
                  Intent i = new Intent( context, EmployeeActivity.class ); 
                int empid=employeelist.get( position ).getEMPLOYEEID();

                i.putExtra( "emp_id", empid );
                i.putExtra( Variables.EmployeeType, 1 );

                context.startActivity(i);




            }
        } );


        convertView.setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick( View v )
            {
              Log.e( "", "Long clickeddddddd" );

              notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }
        } );
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return convertView;

    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView employeename;
        String empname;
        int empid;


       // TextView FreeItemquantity;
      //  CheckBox check1;
    }

     public void filter( String charText )
    {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase( Locale.getDefault() );
        employeelist.clear();
        if ( charText.length() == 0 )
        {

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            employeelist.addAll( arraylist );
        }
        else
        {
            for ( Employee wp : arraylist )
            {
                if ( wp.getNAME().toLowerCase( Locale.getDefault() ).contains( charText ) )
                {
                    employeelist.add( wp );
                }
            }
            if ( employeelist.size() < 1 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Matches Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText( context, " No Matches Found ", 1 );
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /*public ItemClicked getItem(int position){

        return items.get(position);
        }*/


}
```